# Making an R package using RcppArmadillo in Rstudio meets error "undefined reference to dsyev"

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to figure out an error that stopped me from making an R package "whyNotWork" using RcppArmadillo. The package contains only one .cpp file with one simple function which returns the eigen values of a matrix:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec getEigenValues(arma::mat M) 
{
    return arma::eig_sym(M);
}
```

In the DESCRIPTION file I added:

```
Imports:
    Rcpp (>= 0.12.1), RcppArmadillo
LinkingTo:
    Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
Depends: RcppArmadillo
```

In the NAMESPACE file I added:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
useDynLib(whyNotWork)
import(RcppArmadillo)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
```

That function works fine if I was not trying to make a package--the "source" button will successfully load the function and it works correctly. However, when making the package, hitting the "Build & Reload" button will give the following error:

> arma.o:arma.cpp(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib7eig_symIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColIT_EERKNS_4BaseIS5_T0_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib7eig_symIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColIT_EERKNS_4BaseIS5_T0_EE]+0x28d):
>   undefined reference to `dsyev_'

I googled "dsyev" and it seems to be related to LAPCAK..

---

A solution:

New a .txt file in the src folder. Add

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

in the file.

Rename the txt file as Makevars.win (if it's not Windows system, no .win). Package is successfully made.

The solution is found by comparing the files generated from `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` and those from Rstudio

Comment: For the record, that 'solution' is both clearly documented and recommended. It even gets done by our tools.  This was a simple user error, and such the question was closed.

Answer (score 5):

What is your OS?

What does `R CMD config LAPACK_LIBS` return?

Did you build R yourself or did you download a binary?

On most systems (Linux, OS X, ...) R will use external LAPACK libraries. On Windows it may uses its own (reduced) copy of LAPACK which is lacking some functionality.

For what it is worth, your program builds just fine on my system with external LAPACK libraries:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/arma_sym.cpp")
R> v <- 1:4; getEigenValues(v %*% t(v))  
             [,1]
[1,] -2.33587e-15
[2,]  0.00000e+00
[3,]  2.33587e-15
[4,]  3.00000e+01
R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk! sorry to mention that I am using Windows. I just found a way to solve it by comparing the files generated from your RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton() and those from Rstudio. The package is successfully built by adding the "Makevars.win" file in the src folder

Comment: Let's delete the question then. Your package was just built wrong.

Comment: OK, so under Windows, with Rstudio is there any way other than "adding a Makervars.win" file to build a RcppArmadillo package?

Comment: You are supposed to know what you are doing, or use `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`.

Comment: yeah.. I was really confused by these things on a deeper level. Problem is, I was making Rcpp+RcppParallel packages all the time with Rstudio under Windows and they all only require slightly modifications on the DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files

Comment: *Everything* that links against external packages needs `Makevars{.win}`.

Comment: I don't see why this merits deletion of the question; I found this problem through google and it helped me solve my problem. So I guess the question must have some value...I've used RcppArmadillo before with the RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(), but when using RStudio on a new project it also creates a skeleton with Rcpp projects, and I didn't think to change anything to use Armadillo.